# Subversion SSPI Authentication

Tags: authentication, svn

If you want to use SSPI authentication for subversion served by Apache, your users are in multiple domains and users from multiple domains are allowed access to specific repositories but not all repositories, then how do you set that up?

In a previous post, Palehorse indicates the following for using mod_auth_sspi and shows SSPIDOMAIN being set for one domain:

```
<Directory />

    Options FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    AuthType SSPI

    AuthName “YourDomain”

    SSPIAuth On

    SSPIAutheritative Off

    SSPIDomain dc.yourdomain.com

    SSPIOmitDomain Off

    SSPIOfferBasic On

    SSPIUsernameCase Lower

    Require group “YOURDOMAIN\AuthorizedGroup”

</Directory>
```

In my case, I have domain1\user1, domain2\user2, domain3\user3 all needing access to one repository, and domain1\user1, domain3\user3 needing access to another repository. We won't have a RequiredGroup (I don't think - not sure what this is) but rather have each user authenticate with their active directory (windows login) userid and password.

Is there a way to list multiple SSPIDOMAINs and in the access control file list groups similar to the following to allow the users in multiple domains access to repositories?

```
developers=domain1\user1, domain2\user2, domain3\user3
otherReposGrp=domain1\user1, domain3\user3
[/]
@developers=rw
[someOtherRepos]
@otherReposGrp=rw
```

Comment: How did you resolve it? I'm facing the same issue